# reportUndefinedVariable Error implementing Arrays

Tags: python

```
class ArrayImplementation:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.arr = []

    def push(self, data):
        arr.append(data)
```

The error says that in the push function "arr" is not defined. I can't find the bug.

Comment: You missed out `self.`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.arr.append(data)`.
If you want to append to the class property, you have to use the `self.`